# Trazer id na rota

Tags: typescript, angular

Estou fazendo um gerenciamento de usuários. No momento, estou criando o put para editar. Mas, não sei como trazer o id na rota.

Existe uma listagem de usuários e também uma inserção. Quando o cliente clica no botão para recuperar a senha, eu gostaria que já trouxesse o id do usuário e assim realizasse o put.

Está assim o update (o user.id esta vindo undefined pois a rota não esta trazendo):

```
update(user: User) {
        this.endpoint = '/users/' + user.id;
        return this.service.put(this.endpoint, user);
    }
```

E esta assim o put:

```
put(path: String, params) {
        return this.http.put(this.url + path, params, this.standardHeaders()).map((response: Response) => {
            return response.text().length > 0 ? response.json() : {};
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalmente isto e feito da seguinte forma:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute)
userId=0;
ngOnInit() {
 this.route.paramMap
      .subscribe((params: ParamMap) =>  this.userId=params.get('id'))
    //id igual configurdo na sua rota por exemplo /user/:id
};

update(user: User) {
   this.endpoint = '/users/' + this.userId;
   return this.service.put(this.endpoint, user);
}
```

ps: e uma melhor pratica ter o endpoint no service e so passar o id.